# Magento - Create Customer Account form is missing

Tags: magento, account

On a Magento 1.11.1 site (Pro).

When I go to the URL [site]/customer/account/create I should get the form for creating a customer from the file /frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml in block Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register.  Instead there is no such block included (show hints and show blocks enabled).

The customer login form works [site]/customer/account/login by displaying the form from file /frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml in block Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login. This works fine.

I'm using basically the modern theme with modifications (in a separate directory).

Also, customers are still able to create an account via the checkout process.

Is there an configuration parameter that might be set that could disable the standalone 'create customer account' functionality?

Could I have some issue with the templating that is getting in the way of displaying this register block?

So far I have not found the program logic that controls whether the register block is included or removed or anything?  I've checked on file permissions and everything else I could think of, but there is obviously something I am overlooking or not aware of.

Any pointers on discovering the source of the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the logs for any errors? Sometimes blocks will not display if there has been an issue

Comment: Turn on template path hints and see which blocks are included. If the registration fields aren't included make sure they are called in the layout .xml ;)

Comment: Yes, checked the log for errors - nothing there.  Also I have template path hints turned on and no sign of the block.  I'll go back and check the layout.

Comment: Using CommerceBug it appears that all the right xml is included. The AccountController is active.  But, the Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type, Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute, Mage_Catalog_Model_Category, Mage_Cms_Model_Block and Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute are not loaded. And, blocks Mage_Persistent_Block_Form_Remember, Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Name, and Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register are not loaded.  I'm guessing something is missing in the theme.  This theme was originally from 1.5.1.0.